# No Persistence provider for EntityManager named pu1

Tags: java, database, netbeans, netbeans-8

When I run my project I am getting the following error:

```
Compiling 1 source file to C:\Users\Ebola\Desktop\JPASE\JPA\build\classes
warning: [options] bootstrap class path not set in conjunction with -source 1.5
1 warning
compile:
run:
Exception in thread "main" javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager named pu1
at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:85)
at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:54)
at client.Client.main(Client.java:45)
Java Result: 1
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

I already checked the name of my persistence unit and it is correct.

Here is the client class:

public class Client {

```
private static EntityManagerFactory emf;
private static EntityManager em;

public static void main(String[] args) {

    // Create EntityManagerFactory for persistent unit named "pu1"
    // to be used in this test
    emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("pu1");

    // Persist all entities
    createTransactionalEntityManager();
    System.out.println("Inserting Customer and Orders... " + testInsert());
    closeTransactionalEntityManager();

    // Test query and navigation
    createEntityManager();
    System.out.println("Verifying that all are inserted... " + verifyInsert());
    closeEntityManager();

    // Get a detached instance in a new EntityManager
    createEntityManager();
    Customer c = findCustomer("Joe Smith");
    closeEntityManager();

    // Remove all entities
    createTransactionalEntityManager();
    System.out.println("Removing all... " + testDelete(c));
    closeTransactionalEntityManager();

    // Query the results
    createEntityManager();
    System.out.println("Verifying that all are removed... " + verifyDelete());
    closeEntityManager();

}

private static String testInsert() {

    // Create new customer
    Customer customer0 = new Customer();
    customer0.setId(1);
    customer0.setName("Joe Smith");

    // Persist the customer
    em.persist(customer0);

    // Create 2 orders
    Order order1 = new Order();
    order1.setId(100);
    order1.setAddress("123 Main St. Anytown, USA");

    Order order2 = new Order();
    order2.setId(200);
    order2.setAddress("567 1st St. Random City, USA");

    // Associate orders with the customer. The association 
    // must be set on both sides of the relationship: on the 
    // customer side for the orders to be persisted when 
    // transaction commits, and on the order side because it 
    // is the owning side.
    customer0.getOrders().add(order1);
    order1.setCustomer(customer0);

    customer0.getOrders().add(order2);
    order2.setCustomer(customer0);

    return "OK";
}

private static String verifyInsert() {

    Customer c = findCustomer("Joe Smith");

    Collection<Order> orders = c.getOrders();
    if (orders == null || orders.size() != 2) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Unexpected number of orders: " 
                + ((orders == null)? "null" : "" + orders.size()));
    }

    return "OK";
}

private static String testDelete(Customer c) {

    // Merge the customer to the new persistence context
    Customer c0 = em.merge(c);

    // Delete all records.
    em.remove(c0);

    return "OK";
}

private static String verifyDelete() {

    Query q = em.createQuery("select c from Customer c");
    List results = q.getResultList();

    if (results == null || results.size() != 0) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Unexpected number of customers after delete");
    }

    q = em.createQuery("select o from Order o");
    results = q.getResultList();

    if (results == null || results.size() != 0) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Unexpected number of orders after delete");
    }

    return "OK";
}

private static Customer findCustomer(String name) {

    Query q = em.createQuery("select c from Customer c where c.name = :name");
    q.setParameter("name", name);
    return (Customer)q.getSingleResult();

}

private static void createTransactionalEntityManager() {

    // Create a new EntityManager
    em = emf.createEntityManager();

    // Begin transaction
    em.getTransaction().begin();
}

private static void closeTransactionalEntityManager() {

    // Commit the transaction
    em.getTransaction().commit();

    // Close this EntityManager
    em.close();
}

private static void createEntityManager() {

    // Create a new EntityManager
    em = emf.createEntityManager();
}

private static void closeEntityManager() {

    // Close this EntityManager
    em.close();
}
```

}

Now here is my persistence class:

```
package javax.persistence;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceProvider;

public class Persistence {

    public static final String PERSISTENCE_PROVIDER =        "javax.persistence.spi.PeristenceProvider";
protected static final Set<PersistenceProvider> providers;
private static final String SERVICE_NAME;
private static final String PERSISTENCE_XML_NAME = "META-INF/persistence.xml";
private static final Pattern nonCommentPattern;

public Persistence() {
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Compiled Code">
    /* 0: aload_0
     * 1: invokespecial java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
     * 4: return
     *  */
    // </editor-fold>
}

public static EntityManagerFactory createEntityManagerFactory(String persistenceUnitName) {
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Compiled Code">
    /* 0: aload_0
     * 1: aconst_null
     * 2: invokestatic  javax/persistence/Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory:(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/util/Map;)Ljavax/persistence/EntityManagerFactory;
     * 5: areturn
     *  */
    // </editor-fold>
}

public static EntityManagerFactory createEntityManagerFactory(String persistenceUnitName, Map properties) {
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Compiled Code">
    /* 0: aconst_null
     * 1: astore_2
     * 2: aconst_null
     * 3: astore_3
     * 4: invokestatic  javax/persistence/Persistence.findAllProviders:()Ljava/util/Set;
     * 7: astore_3
     * 8: goto          13
     * 11: astore        4
     * 13: new           java/util/HashMap
     * 16: dup
     * 17: invokespecial java/util/HashMap."<init>":()V
     * 20: astore        4
     * 22: new           java/util/HashSet
     * 25: dup
     * 26: invokespecial java/util/HashSet."<init>":()V
     * 29: astore        5
     * 31: aload_3
     * 32: invokeinterface java/util/Set.iterator:()Ljava/util/Iterator;
     * 37: astore        6
     * 39: aload         6
     * 41: invokeinterface java/util/Iterator.hasNext:()Z
     * 46: ifeq          123
     * 49: aload         6
     * 51: invokeinterface java/util/Iterator.next:()Ljava/lang/Object;
     * 56: checkcast     javax/persistence/spi/PersistenceProvider
     * 59: astore        7
     * 61: aload         7
     * 63: aload_0
     * 64: aload_1
     * 65: invokeinterface javax/persistence/spi/PersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory:(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/util/Map;)Ljavax/persistence/EntityManagerFactory;
     * 70: astore_2
     * 71: aload_2
     * 72: ifnull        78
     * 75: goto          123
     * 78: aload         5
     * 80: aload         7
     * 82: invokevirtual java/lang/Object.getClass:()Ljava/lang/Class;
     * 85: invokevirtual java/lang/Class.getName:()Ljava/lang/String;
     * 88: invokeinterface java/util/Set.add:(Ljava/lang/Object;)Z
     * 93: pop
     * 94: goto          120
     * 97: astore        8
     * 99: aload         4
     * 101: aload         7
     * 103: invokevirtual java/lang/Object.getClass:()Ljava/lang/Class;
     * 106: invokevirtual java/lang/Class.getName:()Ljava/lang/String;
     * 109: aload         8
     * 111: invokestatic  javax/persistence/Persistence.createErrorMessage:(Ljava/lang/Throwable;)Ljava/lang/String;
     * 114: invokeinterface java/util/Map.put:(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;
     * 119: pop
     * 120: goto          39
     * 123: aload_2
     * 124: ifnonnull     481
     * 127: new           java/lang/StringBuffer
     * 130: dup
     * 131: new           java/lang/StringBuilder
     * 134: dup
     * 135: invokespecial java/lang/StringBuilder."<init>":()V
     * 138: ldc           No Persistence provider for EntityManager named
     * 140: invokevirtual java/lang/StringBuilder.append:(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
     * 143: aload_0
     * 144: invokevirtual java/lang/StringBuilder.append:(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
     * 147: ldc           :
     * 149: invokevirtual java/lang/StringBuilder.append:(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
     * 152: invokevirtual java/lang/StringBuilder.toString:()Ljava/lang/String;
     * 155: invokespecial java/lang/StringBuffer."<init>":(Ljava/lang/String;)V
     * 158: astore        6
     * 160: ldc           META-INF/persistence.xml
     * 162: invokestatic  javax/persistence/Persistence.exists:(Ljava/lang/String;)Z
     * 165: ifne          179
     * 168: aload         6
     * 170: ldc            No META-INF/persistence.xml was found in classpath.\n
     * 172: invokevirtual java/lang/StringBuffer.append:(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuffer;
     * 175: pop
     * 176: goto          468
     * 179: invokestatic  javax/persistence/Persistence.getReasons:()Ljava/util/Map;
     * 182: astore        7
     * 184: aload         7
     * 186: invokeinterface java/util/Map.entrySet:()Ljava/util/Set;
     * 191: invokeinterface java/util/Set.iterator:()Ljava/util/Iterator;
     * 196: astore        8
     * 198: aload         8
     * 200: invokeinterface java/util/Iterator.hasNext:()Z
     * 205: ifeq          283
     * 208: aload         8
     * 210: invokeinterface java/util/Iterator.next:()Ljava/lang/Object;
     * 215: checkcast     java/util/Map$Entry
     * 218: astore        9
     * 220: aload         6
     * 222: ldc           Provider named
     * 224: invokevirtual java/lang/StringBuffer.append:(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuffer;
     * 227: pop
     * 228: aload         6
     * 230: aload         9
     * 232: invokeinterface java/util/Map$Entry.getKey:()Ljava/lang/Object;
     * 237: invokevirtual java/lang/StringBuffer.append:(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/StringBuffer;
     * 240: pop
     * 241: aload         6
     * 243: ldc            threw exception at initialization:
     * 245: invokevirtual java/lang/StringBuffer.append:(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuffer;
     * 248: pop
     * 249: aload         6
     * 251: new           java/lang/StringBuilder
     * 254: dup
     * 255: invokespecial java/lang/StringBuilder."<init>":()V
     * 258: aload         9
     * 260: invokeinterface java/util/Map$Entry.getValue:()Ljava/lang/Object;
     * 265: invokevirtual java/lang/StringBuilder.append:(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
     * 268: ldc           \n
     * 270: invokevirtual java/lang/StringBuilder.append:(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
     * 273: invokevirtual java/lang/StringBuilder.toString:()Ljava/lang/String;
     * 276: invokevirtual java/lang/StringBuffer.append:(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuffer;
     * 279: pop
     * 280: goto          198
     * 283: aload         4
     * 285: invokeinterface java/util/Map.entrySet:()Ljava/util/Set;
     * 290: invokeinterface java/util/Set.iterator:()Ljava/util/Iterator;
     * 295: astore        8
     * 297: aload         8
     * 299: invokeinterface java/util/Iterator.hasNext:()Z
     * 304: ifeq          382
     * 307: aload         8
     * 309: invokeinterface java/util/Iterator.next:()Ljava/lang/Object;
     * 314: checkcast     java/util/Map$Entry
     * 317: astore        9
     * 319: aload         6
     * 321: ldc           Provider named
     * 323: invokevirtual java/lang/StringBuffer.append:(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuffer;
     * 326: pop
     * 327: aload         6
     * 329: aload         9
     * 331: invokeinterface java/util/Map$Entry.getKey:()Ljava/lang/Object;
     * 336: invokevirtual java/lang/StringBuffer.append:(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/StringBuffer;
     * 339: pop
     * 340: aload         6
     * 342: ldc            threw unexpected exception at create EntityManagerFactory: \n
     * 344: invokevirtual java/lang/StringBuffer.append:(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuffer;
     * 347: pop
     * 348: aload         6
     * 350: new           java/lang/StringBuilder
     * 353: dup
     * 354: invokespecial java/lang/StringBuilder."<init>":()V
     * 357: aload         9
     * 359: invokeinterface java/util/Map$Entry.getValue:()Ljava/lang/Object;
     * 364: invokevirtual java/lang/StringBuilder.append:(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
     * 367: ldc           \n
     * 369: invokevirtual java/lang/StringBuilder.append:(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
     * 372: invokevirtual java/lang/StringBuilder.toString:()Ljava/lang/String;
     * 375: invokevirtual java/lang/StringBuffer.append:(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuffer;
     * 378: pop
     * 379: goto          297
     * 382: aload         5
     * 384: invokeinterface java/util/Set.isEmpty:()Z
     * 389: ifne          468
     * 392: aload         6
     * 394: ldc            The following providers:\n
     * 396: invokevirtual java/lang/StringBuffer.append:(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuffer;
     * 399: pop
     * 400: aload         5
     * 402: invokeinterface java/util/Set.iterator:()Ljava/util/Iterator;
     * 407: astore        8
     * 409: aload         8
     * 411: invokeinterface java/util/Iterator.hasNext:()Z
     * 416: ifeq          460
     * 419: aload         8
     * 421: invokeinterface java/util/Iterator.next:()Ljava/lang/Object;
     * 426: checkcast     java/lang/String
     * 429: astore        9
     * 431: aload         6
     * 433: new           java/lang/StringBuilder
     * 436: dup
     * 437: invokespecial java/lang/StringBuilder."<init>":()V
     * 440: aload         9
     * 442: invokevirtual java/lang/StringBuilder.append:(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
     * 445: ldc           \n
     * 447: invokevirtual java/lang/StringBuilder.append:(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
     * 450: invokevirtual java/lang/StringBuilder.toString:()Ljava/lang/String;
     * 453: invokevirtual java/lang/StringBuffer.append:(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuffer;
     * 456: pop
     * 457: goto          409
     * 460: aload         6
     * 462: ldc           Returned null to createEntityManagerFactory.\n
     * 464: invokevirtual java/lang/StringBuffer.append:(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuffer;
     * 467: pop
     * 468: new           javax/persistence/PersistenceException
     * 471: dup
     * 472: aload         6
     * 474: invokevirtual java/lang/StringBuffer.toString:()Ljava/lang/String;
     * 477: invokespecial javax/persistence/PersistenceException."<init>":(Ljava/lang/String;)V
     * 480: athrow
     * 481: aload_2
     * 482: areturn
     * Exception table:
     * from    to  target type
     * 4     8    11   Class java/io/IOException
     * 61    75    97   Class java/lang/Throwable
     * 78    94    97   Class java/lang/Throwable
     *  */
    // </editor-fold>
}
```

**What can I do to fix this? **

Comment: Is there an appropriate persistence.xml file within your Meta-inf folder?

Comment: Ok than check the the persitence unit name which must be pu1 and check if the connection properties are correct. Host port user passwort and so on